# Using IntelliJ idea debugger attach android service or activity at the first beginning?

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea

I got an android project build via ant commandline workflow, edit/debug it with IntelliJ idea.

I could attach debugger to the service or running activities when the apps running. I want to set the breakpoint to the very beginning of the service initialize flow, make the app restart and keep the debugger attached, but I don't know how to achieve  it.

To debug windows program, windbg's `open executable` will do the work, what about android apps?

**Update:**

I got an extra service in my app, I'd want to make the service wait for the debugger. it has its own process `android:process=":service"`. How can I achieve this?

Maybe the solution is just add these code to the service onCreate function, when I want to debug it?

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

Answer (score 3):

On your phone go to Developer options -> Select debug app, and select your app. Then, check the "Wait for debugger". When you start your app, a popup will open with something like "Waiting for a debugger to attach".

After that, just attach the debugger in IntelliJ.

P.S. Not sure how it is in Ant, but with Maven, you could specify the "Wait for debugger" when running the build.